# Complex coordinates in curved space

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, general-relativity

Given a curved 4-dimensional space with a real-valued metric tensor and real-valued coordinate vectors (e.g., a Minkowski space), is it always possible to describe the same space using coordinate vectors having one imaginary component and three real components, by appropriately changing the metric tensor?

The background of this question is that the use of the (ict,x1,x2,x3) coordinate vector has fallen out of favor in descriptions of relativistic 4-space, and has been replaced by (ct, x1,x2,x3) plus the Minkowski metric tensor whose values on the diagonal are -1,1,1,1  and zero off-diagonal.  In a flat space the two approaches are exactly equivalent.  However, the (ict,x1,x2,x3) approach is almost never used for curved spaces.  Why?  Is there a reason it *can't* be used for curved spaces?  The only important thing that seems to distinguish between the two approaches is the number of free parameters in a 4 x 4 complex metric tensor: 10 in the first approach and and perhaps 16 in the second approach.

Comment: AFAICT the primary benefit to the 'imaginary time' version is primarily that it let you use a 'Euclidean' norm $\sqrt{x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$ to write your metric, but that's essentially impossible once you start curving space anyway. (Also, you really should work in units where $c=1$. Everyone else does. :-) )

Comment: It seems that the extra free parameters in the complex metric that would go with an "imaginary time" version might be useful.

Comment: It's not really a 'complex metric', though; everything else is real. The 'imaginary' component is _only_ purely imaginary, so there's no difference in DOF between the two formulations.

Comment: I'm hoping that there is a discipline in differential geometry that considers spaces with complex coordinates and complex metric tensors.  Haven't found it yet.

Comment: There certainly is; see, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kähler_manifold or similar. But this question explicitly asks about 4-dimensional real metrics, presumably in a physical context, and complex differential geometry is at a bit of a remove from that.

Comment: I know that usually the metric tensor is considered to be real, but did ask about a complex metric: " The only important thing that seems to distinguish between the two approaches is the number of free parameters in a 4 x 4 complex metric tensor...".  I have found some good sources in the meantime, including Complex Manifolds and Mathematical Physics [https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f884/222d1ed9926cbc1d03a6d2e2927c177afe69.pdf]